# few errors with malloc,arguments,memory leak etc

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define LOOPS 100
#define RAYSIZE 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *pointer = NULL;

    for(count=0; count<LOOPS; count++) {
        pointer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * RAYSIZE);
    }
    free(pointer);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking memory for first 99 times, as your free call is outside of loop. Only the last allocated memory is freed.

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the loop you allocation some memory and set `pointer` to point to it.  When you do that `pointer` is no longer pointing to the last piece of memory, but it's still allocated to your program.  When you call `free(pointer)` you're only freeing the last block of memory you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have as many calls to `malloc` as to `free`. Here you call `malloc` in a loop, which mean that you will have many more calls to it than to `free`.